# Calcular la media de una columna de una lista de listas en R

Tags: r, lista, rstudio, apply

Quisiera saber como calcular la media de una columna de una lista de listas en R.
Es decir, tengo un objeto lista (llamado BAF2) de 600.000 listas. Y en cada una de esas listas, tengo 4 columnas (animal, cromosoma, posición, BAF). Yo quiero calcular la media de una de esas columnas (BAF) en todas las listas.
He intentado esta función, pero me da warning porque creo que me calcula la media de todas las columnas para cada lista.

```
BASF <- lapply(BAF2, function(x) {mean(x$BAF, na.rm =T)})
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: El código que muestras debería hacer lo que estás diciendo en tu pregunta si los datos son como dices, si tienes un Warning, agrega la información del mismo y también agrega la estructura del objeto `str(BAF2)`

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener una lista de tu BASF puedes hacer lo siguiente :

```
 BASF[1]
```

Si lo que quieres es quedarte con una de las columnas de la lista que seleccionada haz lo siguiente:

```
BASF[[1]][["BAF"]]
```

Así ya solo nos quedamos con la columna BAF

Ahora bien si lo que queremos es realizar este cálculo para todas las listas , pero solo sobre esa columna , debemos aplicar lapply aplicando la función mean()

```
BASF <- lapply(BASF[[1:length(BASF)]][["BAF"]], mean(),na.rm =TRUE)
```

Espero que te funcione :)